# What can i do about : Enter username and password for "" at http://localhost in Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, localhost, webbrowser-control

Some times when i want to run and debug my asp.net projects and see it on Firefox browser, i see a window that ask me `Username` and `Password` for `http://localhost` IIS.
I find this solution and think maybe is useful for others.
So decide to share it with you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open firefox and type in the address bar about:config
2. type `ntlm` in the textbox.
3. Double click on `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` and type `localhost` there.
4. Click on OK.

You are done.

Comment: Does this require admin privileges?

Comment: What are the implications/effects of this?

Comment: @YashSaraiya ,I do it on my PC that I'm admin system and don't test it in other privileges.you can test it and aware me ;)

Comment: After step 3, I got the following warning!!! (http://i.imgsafe.org/09c0af1.png) I am working in an organization and don't know whether continuing from here would violate any of the policies of my organization

Comment: @YashSaraiya, this image warning you that if you manipulate or change some features in Mozilla Firefox,then if you see any abnormal Mozilla work,they(Mozilla Co.) doesn't responsible about it.
in other hand this is confirm message.
if( you know that,what do you want to do)
don't worry,and continue 
else
break down your action.

Answer (score 2):

Open firefox and type in the address bar about:config
type ntlm in the textbox.
Double click on network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris and type localhost there.
Click on OK.It works perfectly