# "Authentication Required" - ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I have created a simple **login.aspx** page with SQL Server Database. There are no build Errors/Warnings. However when I click on "View in Browser", it prompts me to "Enter username and password for http://localhost:xxxx".

What is causing this and How do I overcome this.

**NOTE:** I am using Visual Studio 2010 Premium, .Net Framework 4.0

**Edit 1:** I did the following in my **web.config** file:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
<authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
```

But still the authentication popup comes up as shown in image below:

[image: Authentication Popup]

**Edit 2:** I followed these steps as answered in this question [What can i do about : Enter username and password for "" at http://localhost in Firefox browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869456/what-can-i-do-about-enter-username-and-password-for-at-http-localhost-in)

1. Open firefox and type in the address bar about:config
2. type ntlm in the textbox.
3. Double click on network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris and type localhost there.
4. Click on OK.

However after **Step 3**, I am seeing this screen:

[image]

**Note: I don't have admin privileges**

Will continuing from here violate the limited privileges I have and take admin control / change settings which only admin would have been capable of?

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using?

Comment: Are you talking about this in **web.config**? "<system.web>
   <!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>" I haven't used any of these

Comment: If you are then doing your own authentication, specify `authentication mode="None"`

Comment: Can someone post the image from the link... I am unable to do so.... @stuartd check updated question (Edit 1)

Comment: Might have nothing to do with your web site at all, e.g. if your browser is using a proxy server and the proxy server requires authentication.

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: @JohnWu How do I check whether my browser is using a proxy server?